# ImportError: No Module named demiso in Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm new to the Jython and I'm trying to run a python class using Jython in Java. But I'm running into some issues.

> The Java class that I've defined:

```
public class DemistoCalls {

    PythonInterpreter interpreter = null;


    public DemistoCalls()
    {
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(),
                System.getProperties(), new String[0]);

        this.interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
    }

    void execfile( final String fileName )
    {
        this.interpreter.execfile(fileName);
    }

    PyInstance createClass( final String className, final String opts )
    {
        return (PyInstance) this.interpreter.eval(className + "(" + opts + ")");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemistoCalls demistoCalls = new DemistoCalls();

        demistoCalls.execfile("C:\\Users\\AlokNath\\Desktop\\Demisto_Project\\demisto-py-master\\demisto\\SimpleConnect.py");

    }

}
```

> The SampleConnect.py file that I'm trying to run:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\AlokNath\Desktop\Demisto_Project\demisto-py-
master\demisto")
import demisto
```

While Running the java file, I'm getting this error:

`File "C:\Users\AlokNath\Desktop\Demisto_Project\demisto-py-master\demisto\SimpleConnect.py", line 3, in <module>
    import demisto
ImportError: No module named demisto`

Although I've defined the "demisto" module in the system path and checked that the system path in python contains the appropriate path to Jython 2.7.lb2 Library. I'm not sure where am I going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the import error problem. We need to copy the missing module to the “site-packages” folder under "modeler-installation/lib/jython/Lib". This will resolve the dependency problem.